# varchar2 and number data type cause error in SQL query editor in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, types, phpmyadmin

I am trying to practice SQL and proceed to PL/SQL with the set of exercises given to me (the set of exercises is based on Oracle SQL).

I wanted to do the SQL query exercises on my laptop by starting on basics like creating tables and querying them, and I tried it before in academia, but the exercises given to me seem to be in another form and I need to learn that type of SQL query.

I used PHPMyAdmin SQL, but it seems it won't accept data type `varchar2([some num])` and `number([some num])` and always indicates there is an error in my syntax.
I know that this error just stems from syntax incompatibility (since I tried it in another program once, but I forgot what it was, and I am trying to learn again and master it).

So how do I get it to work? Or what other programs can I use to start to practice this form of SQL query which accepts `varchar2` and `number` data types?

Answer (score 2):

`varchar2` and `number` are Oracle data types. MySQL's equivalents are `varchar` and `numeric`, respectively.

Comment: I sort of thought of that but can you suggest some programs wherein I could practice Oracle SQL queries? Or turn phpmyadmin sql editor to Oracle compatible queries? Thank you so much.

Comment: You can download [Oracle Express](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/overview/index.html) for free and use SQL*Plus to run queries against it. Alternatively, you could use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) online.

Comment: Thank you very much and will try it as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

@jane deuschandell
You can also try the following link of oracle live SQL on the Oracle Website for practicing queries:

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000:123714391827300:::::